# First match with numbers on jersey

Tags: cricket, trivia, history

Can any one tell me which was the first match where the first time numbers were printed on jersey, for all domestic and international including men and women. As I am so curious to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

This was difficult to find since numbering had little to no guidelines in early cricket and as a result probably wasn't recorded, however it appears the first recorded game of *International Cricket* to have numbered players was the 1995/1996 *World Series*. See: [ODI/T20 Number History](http://www.espncricinfo.com/australia/content/story/209641.html) and [1995/1996 World Series Records](http://www.espncricinfo.com/nz/engine/series/60978.html)

But, the first *World Cup* to have numbered players was in 1999. Although the first *World Cup* to ever occur was in 1992, they did not initially number players because they did not want to copy football. The 1999 World Cup is often considered the first official numbering of cricket players instead of the 1995/1996 World Series. See: 
[1999 World Cup](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/61046.html)

Another note is that the first test players, who may not have had a number on their jerseys, but are still numbered as a test player (in records) are Tom Armitage of England and Charles Bannerman of Australia on March 15, 1877. Bannerman is often more well known because he faced the first ball ever bowled in Test cricket and also scored the first run in Test cricket. To clarify, they are not actual numbers on a jersey, just test cricketer 1, 2 and so on. See: [1st Test](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/17735/coverage/62396/Australia-vs-England-1st-Test-England-tour-of-Australia-1876-77)